# Not able to get the accurate count during aggregation based on condition

Tags: sql, hive, bigdata

I have a table named tbl1. Which contains 3 columns empId,Designation and salaryScale

```
empId   Designation     salaryScale
Arun    Developer          1
Kiran   Developer          0
Anu     ITA                2
```

I would like to get the total no of people having a particular designation as DesCount and need to get the salaryScale count for each designation where salaryScale > 0 and aggregate them on designation level.

Below is my query and output

> select Designation,count(Designation) as DesCount,count(salaryScale)
>   as scaleCount from tbl1 where salaryScale>0 group by Designation;

```
Designation DesCount    scaleCount
Developer       1       1
ITA             1       1
```

But what I expect is

```
Designation DesCount    scaleCount
Developer       2       1
ITA             1       1
```

because for Developer designation the total count is 2 .

Am I doing anything wrong in my query?

Answer (score 1):

You can try below using `case when expression` and remove `where condition`

your where condition is filtering out then it counts so you are not getting desired result

```
select Designation,count(Designation) as DesCount,
count(case when salaryScale>0 then 1 end) as scaleCount 
from tbl1  
group by Designation
```

Answer (score 1):

use case expression

```
select Designation,count(Designation) as DesCount,
sum(case when salaryScale>0 then 1 else 0 end) as scaleCount 
from table_name  
group by Designation
```